Changing multiple file names based off of a spreadsheet
It's been a while since I've done any code, and I can't remember much of what I am doing, but I ran into an issue where I am needing to change a lot of file names (I did it manually once, but turns out I need to do it again, and want an easy way to keep changing them if needed)
Anyways: I have a csv file with the old file name and the new file name.

I did a quick chatGPT question to see if I could find a quick and dirty solution (don't use chatGPT much) and it gave me something that didn't work.
I don't really know what I am doing, just hoping to not manually change all of these files. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Be warned, AI content cannot be posted.

@histrueandfalse Thanks! Sorry haven't used stackoverflow since before AI started becoming much of a thing. I edited my post. Appreciate the heads up.

No Worries, I've been in trouble for the same reason, in fact, i'm under a question ban for that LOL. Anyways, Enjoy!

Where those files are living? In same directory as FilenameChanges.csv?

Please make an earnest attempt and provide an [mre] showing where you are stuck. If you really have no idea to start, I would suggest starting with searches for How to Read and Write CSV files,  Python csv library docs, How to rename a file in Python, and the Python 3 os.rename() docs

Your original question showed your coding attempt which is desired by stackoverflow posts.  Although the code was written by chatgpt this code is allowed  in the question as long as the question itself is not written by chatgpt per Should we flag human-written questions that use code generated by ChatGPT?

@DarrylG OK thanks for the clarification!

Was able to find a solution. I found it easier to find a solution using Powershell than python.
$csvPath = "C:\Workspace\Code\FilenameChange.csv"

$directory = "C:\Workspace\Code\Files"

$filenames = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

foreach ($file in $filenames) {
    $oldFileName = $file.old_filename +".png"
    $newFileName = $file.new_filename+".png"

    # Create full paths for the old and new file names
    $oldFilePath = Join-Path -Path $directory -ChildPath $oldFileName
    $newFilePath = Join-Path -Path $directory -ChildPath $newFileName

    # Check if the old file exists
    if (Test-Path -Path $oldFilePath) {
        Rename-Item -Path $oldFilePath -NewName $newFileName
        Write-Host "Renamed: $oldFileName -> $newFileName"
    } else {
        Write-Host "File not found: $oldFileName"
    }
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

I am not sure if python was running into issues due to the filename being non standard characters? a Unicode issue or something? Either way, Powershell script worked well for me.

Given a CSV named FilenameChange.csv that lives in the same directory as all files to be renamed, then the following code would accomplish renaming all files:
from os import rename

with open("FilenameChange.csv", "r") as file:
    next(file)

    for line in file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()

        if not stripped_line:
            continue

        old_name, new_name = stripped_line.split(",")
        rename(old_name, new_name)

The code opens the CSV file, skips the first header line, and then for each line after that (assuming it's not empty) splits it into the old name and new name, and then uses the os.rename function to rename it. If the new_name already exists, then an error will be raised. If some of the new_name files already exist, it may be useful to add a check for os.path.isfile before trying the rename.

Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the filetypes being chinese characters? The reason I needed to change the files to begin with was another application not reading the file types as characters but intead searching for a unicode/ASCII or something.

The issue is probably due to the encoding of the CSV file.
Try this:
import os
import sys

with open("FilenameChange.csv", encoding="utf-8") as data:
    next(data) # skip header
    for line in map(str.rstrip, data):
        try:
            os.rename(*line.split(","))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, file=sys.stderr)

